# MVC4, EF : Create new object with "hierarchical" one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, persistence, one-to-many

I'm having problem with creating an object. My entity has a "hierarchical" one-to-many relationship. A division can belong to another division. 
Here is my entity:

```
    //Properties
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [Column("DivisionName", Order = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual Division ParentDivision { get; set; }
```

Here is my method to create a new division:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ParentDivision = new SelectList(db.Divisions, "DivisionId", "Name");
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Division division)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Divisions.Add(division);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ParentDivision = new SelectList(db.Divisions, "DivisionId", "Name", division.ParentDivision.DivisionId);
        return View(division);
    }
```

In this case, when I try to create a division that belongs to another division, i get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

I've also tried to change the ViewBag like this:

```
ViewBag.ParentDivision = new SelectList(db.Divisions, "ParentDivision.DivisionId", "Name", division.ParentDivision.DivisionId);
```

Here, the object is created, but without the parent division...

I'm really confused... If someone has any idea... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean "circular"? i.e. Division A owns B which owns A? Or do you mean "hierarchical"? A owns B, C, D; C owns E, F etc. but it never comes back to A?

Comment: @AdamBenson Yes, sorry, as you say, it's hierarchical, not circular, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that it's a self-referencing relationship. If `ParentDivision` hasn't been set yet, it will be null, and null does not have a `DivisionId` property, hence your exception.

You need to do a null check before reference the property. Probably the easiest method in this instance would be using a ternary:

```
division.ParentDivision != null ? division.ParentDivision.DivisionId : null
```

However, you shouldn't need to set the selected value, anyways. Razer will take care of this automatically. You also don't need to create an actual `SelectList`. All `Html.DropDownListFor` needs is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If you pass it that, the helper will take care of creating the `SelectList` and setting the appropriate selected value, if applicable.

```
ViewBag.ParentDivision = db.Divisions.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.DivisionId, Text = m.Name });
```

Then:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentDivisionId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ParentDivision)
```

Which brings up another matter. You currently don't have a property to actually bind to. You can't use `ParentDivision` directly, because the select list will only post back the id, not an full `ParentDivision` instance. You need a property to bind the posted id to, which is a good practice to include on your entity anyways:

```
[ForeignKey("ParentDivision")]
public int ParentDivisionId { get; set; }
public virtual Division ParentDivision { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Actually I deleted all my entity and redid it taking into account your last point. I also added a collection of children and when I updated the database, I saw the difference in the table generated.